# Disable double click event on Lookup column in sharepoint 2013 using jQuery/javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a lookup field named 'department' with multiple values allowed in SharePoint 2013 form.
I want to disable the column based on another field Status.  If status is 3, 'department' can't be undated anymore.

I write a code, see below.

```
$("select[title *= 'department']").closest('tr').attr('disabled', true);
$("select[title *= 'department']").off('dblclick');
```

It looks good to disable the columns and 2 buttons 'Add' and 'Remove'.  But when I make a double click on the possible value on the left side, it auto move the 1st value, 'lab',  to the right side and active '' button.  Only this value 'lab' can be moved.  Other values are still disabled.

One click is disabled.  How can I disable the double click? Thanks!

Comment: can you show your click event ?

Comment: click is disabled, I can't disable double click.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to override adding and removing items in Sharepoint lookup multi control. This works equally well with pressing Add/Remove buttons and with double-clicking in the lists.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(function ()
{
    var addButton = document.querySelector("input[id$='_AddButton']");
    addButton.setAttribute("onbeforeadd", "OnBeforeAdd");
    addButton.setAttribute("onafteradd", "OnAfterAdd");

    var removeButton = document.querySelector("input[id$='_RemoveButton']");
    removeButton.setAttribute("onbeforeremove", "OnBeforeRemove");
    removeButton.setAttribute("onafterremove", "OnAfterRemove");
});

function OnBeforeAdd()
{
    //TODO
    //....

    return true; //return false if you want to ignore adding
}
function OnAfterAdd()
{
    //TODO
    //....
}
function OnBeforeRemove()
{
    //TODO
    //....

    return true; //return false if you want to ignore removing
}
function OnAfterRemove()
{
    //TODO
    //....
}
```